# Prototype hide the div that has a specific link (<a href)

Tags: select, html, prototypejs, href

I have the following HTML:

```
<div> <a href="http://google.com"> Google </a></div>
```

I am using prototype library. I need to hide the div that has the link http://google.com with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prototype:

```
$$('div a[href="http://google.com"]').each(function (e) { Element.hide(e.parentNode); })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS to do this.

```
<div class="hideMe"> <a href="http://google.com"> Google </a></div>
```

and then in a CSS do :

```
#hideMe {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) available to you?

If so, use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href=http://www.google.com]').parent('div').hide();
});
```

If the parent is not necessarily on the immediate next level in the DOM, use `.parents` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href=http://www.google.com]').parents('div').hide();
});
```

However that might affect `div`s on an even higher level in the tree.